# What are the most common mistakas people do when wireframing?

Tags: wireframe

What are the most common mistakas people do when wireframing? What screens or alternative versions of a page chunk (such as no javaScripts fallbacks) are usually missing?

Comment: This is a Question and *Answer* site. Not a question and examples site, or a question and discussion site. If your question starts with *"What are some of..."* then it's not something that has a correct answer. Questions need to be practical and answerable. You've used this site for a while but I suggest you re-read the [What not to ask](http://ux.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) section of the help section as this isn't a question that works on this site.

Comment: This is a very good question. Often on this site no core UX questions are asked and we're flooded with visual design and front end implementation questions. I understand your quibble about wording and in this case there are right answers. I feel it's very wrong to put it on hold as few good UX questions come along here.

Comment: If you were in my position – how would you rephrase this question so it will follow the rules? 

I don't want go into an argument about the rules of this site but there are quite a few questions on this forum that could have several different correct answers and I feel that this is one of these questions. This very strict way of defining how a Q&A forum should behave will eventually kill it because people will hesitate to post stuff.

Comment: It's basically a one-line question asking for *everything* that could possibly be left out of *any* wireframe created for *any* situation. There is no correct answer to that. Also, it doesn't seem like it's a practical question - what are you going to do with the answer? You need to leave questions based on an actual problem that you face that you need answering so you can get past that problem. What is the problem you have that needs solving here? It doesn't seem like it *is* that sort of question, it's just a broad 'I'm wondering about...' type post.

Comment: Allright. I'm trying to improve the delivery of wireframes in general and I'm hoping that the answer (or answers) I receive here could lead to a wireframe checklist that contains the most common (not everything) misses. I will use this checklist for the current and future projects that I'm working with and for me that list would be highly practical.

Answer (score 2):

The most common mistake with wireframes is not tailoring the output for the internal audience - that is those that need to use it.

Unless working for the same company / people / process each time then the same deliverable is unlikely to be right for all situations.

Additionally there are times when annotated designs or mid fidelity prototypes are best or, in other situations, a sketch on a whiteboard might all that is needed to get the work done. If wireframes need to be highly detailed it may be a sign that UX and engineering are not working close enough together.